# In which Game of Thrones episode(s) the opening sequence shows the greatest number of locations?

Tags: game-of-thrones, credits

[This link](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Title_sequence) revealed that the title sequence animators are limited in the amount of time they have to animate an opening (the length of the opening song), and the places shown/amount of time it takes to move to each place depends on where the characters are on the map.
Additionally, there are rules such as every opening sequence **must** show King's Landing, Winterfell, The Wall, and wherever Daenerys is.

As the title suggests, I was just wondering which episode's opening sequence shows the most number of locations in the 90 seconds that they have to work with.

Note, I chose "locations" in the title because as far as I can remember all the places shown were cities, but just in case there were any landmarks I wanted to allow them to be included.

Comment: In fact many of the places were not cities, ex. the Wall and most of the castles (like Winterfell).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got your answer in the [link](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Title_sequence#Locations_featured) you provided, you just need to do the counting.

The highest number of locations shown in the single episode so far is six and I suspect this is the maximum due to time constraints. In fact, six locations were being shown in each opening sequence since the second episode of the second season. In the previous episodes, it was either four or five locations.

Comment: Whoops, didn't keep scrolling to the bottom of that page